# What's the meaning of type 'd in q#

Tags: types, q#

[image]

As shown in the picture above. What's the meaning of type 'd? What's type the return value of "Zipped" should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types like `'d` or `'c` appear in the error messages when the Q# compiler fails to infer types of any values involved. In this case, there is a type mismatch between the return of `Zipped`, which is an array of tuples, and the return type of the operation, which from the screenshot looks like `Double[][]`, an array of arrays of double.

Edit: In this particular case the compiler knows the return type produced by `Zipped`, so it should use it instead of a generic. There's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/issues/1395) opened in the Q# compiler repo for this - thank you for bringing this up!